# change custom radio button image onclick

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a button that can change the image when it is clicked, I've tried with changing its opacity now I'm trying to change the image. Here's what I've done for the custom button

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginVertical: normalize(5),
        opacity: 0.5
    },

    activeButton: {
        opacity: 1
    }
});

export default class RadioButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selected: this.props.currentSelection === this.props.value,
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.currentSelection !== prevProps.currentSelection) {
            this.setState({ selected: this.props.currentSelection === this.props.value });
        }
    }

    render() {
        let activeButton = this.props.activeStyle ? this.props.activeStyle : styles.activeButton;

        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, this.props.containerStyle, this.state.selected ? activeButton : null]}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ selected: !this.state.selected });
                    this.props.onPress();
                }}>
                    {
                        this.props.element ?
                            this.props.element :
                            <Text> {this.props.value} </Text>
                    }
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

        );
    }
}
```

It should be like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR84p.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First import both images. one for selected and another for normal state.

```
import selectedImg from '../images/selected.png';
import normalImg from '../images/normal.png';
```

and then add below method to your component

```
btnBackgroundImage() = {
    var imgSource = this.state.selected? selectedImg : normalImg;
    return (
      <Image
        style={'put style here'}
        source={ imgSource }
      />
    );
  }
```

now edit your render method like below

```
render() {
        let activeButton = this.props.activeStyle ? this.props.activeStyle : styles.activeButton;

        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, this.props.containerStyle, this.state.selected ? activeButton : null]}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ selected: !this.state.selected });
                    this.props.onPress();
                }}>
                    {
                       this.btnBackgroundImage()
                    }
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

        );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate it works. But how do i make it for multiple buttons without copy pasting  the codes

Comment: Your welcome. You can upvote and accept my answer if it worked.          You can import RadioButton in your other component and use it for as many buttons. I found one lib https://github.com/danceyoung/react-native-selectmultiple-button , which handling multiple buttons.